# How to avoid numbering of Appendix?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I have only one appendix in my report. But it appears in the table of contents and title page as Appendix A. How can I change it to APPENDIX?

Comment: You can use `\chapter*{Appendix}`.

Comment: And add `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname}` to get appendix entry in `TOC`

Comment: remember `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline` if you are using `hyperref`

Comment: @Sigur: Would you mind adding an answer just for the record?

Answer (score 5):

As commented above (by me and *Harish Kumar*), you can use

```
\chapter*{\appendixname}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname}
```

Note also the *daleif*'s comment.

Comment: Another (maybe devious) trick is to say `\backmatter\chapter{\appendixname}`, if the class supports `\backmatter` (`book`, `scrbook`, `memoir` and others).

Comment: This solution works, but now the appendix sections are called ".1", ".2" etc, which looks a bit weird. Is it possible to keep the "A" (for appendix), as "A.1", "A.2" etc. ?